How to Fetch and Display Receiver's Email in Firebase for a Chat Application in Flutter?
I am developing a chat application using Flutter and Firebase. I need to fetch the receiver's email from Firebase and display it correctly in the chat screen. Additionally, I want to use the receiver's email when sending messages. However, I am encountering issues with fetching and displaying the receiver's email. Below are the details of my current implementation:
Chat Page Code:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenRoute = "ChatPage";

  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  late User? signedInUser;
  TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSignedInUser();
  }

  void getSignedInUser() {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    setState(() {
      signedInUser = user;
    });
  }

  Future<void> sendMessage(String message, String receiverEmail) async {
    try {
      if (signedInUser != null) {
        final messageData = {
          'message': message,
          'senderId': signedInUser!.uid,
          'senderEmail': signedInUser!.email,
          'receiverEmail': receiverEmail,
          'timestamp': Timestamp.now(),
        };

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').add(messageData);
        _messageController.clear();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending message: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final name = args['name'];
    final imageLink = args['ImageLink'];
    final lastSeenTimestamp = args['lastSeen'];
    final receiverEmail = args['receiverEmail'];

    // Convert Firestore Timestamp to DateTime
    DateTime? lastSeenDateTime;
    if (lastSeenTimestamp != null && lastSeenTimestamp is Timestamp) {
      lastSeenDateTime = lastSeenTimestamp.toDate();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageLink),
        ),
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(name),
            Text(
              lastSeenDateTime != null ? formatLastSeen(lastSeenDateTime) : 'Last seen unknown',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('messages')
                  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: false) // Order messages by timestamp
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                  );
                }

                final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: messages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final message = messages[index];
                    final messageText = message['message'];
                    final senderId = message['senderId'];
                    final isMe = signedInUser?.uid == senderId;

                    return MessageReplay(
                      sendmessage: messageText,
                      isMe: isMe,
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _messageController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Type a message...',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () {
                    final message = _messageController.text.trim();
                    if (message.isNotEmpty) {
                      sendMessage(message, receiverEmail); // Use the receiver's email
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessageReplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? sendmessage;
  final bool isMe;

  const MessageReplay({Key? key, this.sendmessage, required this.isMe})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Material(
            elevation: 5,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomLeft: isMe ? Radius.circular(30) : Radius.circular(0),
              bottomRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
            color: isMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Text(
                sendmessage ?? 'Message not found', // Handle null message
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I am encountering issues where the receiver's email is not being fetched correctly and thus not displayed or used in the ChatPage. The receiverEmail in my Firestore messages collection remains as receiver@example.com instead of the actual email.
Screenshot
Here is a screenshot of the data in Firestore:

What I've Tried:
Verified that the fetchReceiverEmail function is correctly retrieving the email from Firestore.
Ensured that the correct arguments are passed to the ChatPage.
Question:
How can I correctly fetch and display the receiver's email from Firestore in my chat application? Any suggestions or improvements to my current approach would be greatly appreciated.
Verified that the fetchReceiverEmail function is correctly retrieving the email from Firestore.
